# Aws RDS MySql master and slave as EC2 MySql replica for Data sync

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

Is it possible to configure Aws RDS Mysql version 8+ as Master and Slave as mysql replica installed in EC2 machine for data sync purpose ??

Tried syncing with RDS master and mysql installed in Ec2 replica but failed,  getting error in GTID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible , and well documented in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html